# Typescript don't really check function type?

Tags: typescript

Giving the below code, type script compiler just don't raise any error, so it just don't check the parameter type of function?

```
var mySearch3:  (source: Person, subString: string)=> boolean  = 
       function()     {return true;}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

TypeScript respects the fact that you can ignore the arguments that are passed.

When you have a definition of a function, any implementation must be compatible by either having the correct type of parameter, or by omitting that parameter.

When calling a function, you must supply all required arguments (arguments that are not optional and don't have a default value).

Let's work some examples using this interface that is for a function that accepts a string and a number:

```
interface Example {
    (name: string, age: number) : string;
}
```

All of the following function are compatible:

```
var a: Example = function() { return 'Hello'; };
var b: Example = function(name: string) { return 'Hello ' + name; };
var c: Example = function(n: string, a: number) { return 'Hello ' + n + ' you are ' + a; };
```

Each one is compatible because it either specifies a parameter of the correct type, or omits it. The key to this is *that they all have to be called in the same way*.

I have to specify both parameters when I call these functions, even if they don't use them. This allows the function to change its implementation without affecting the callers that rely on the public contract (which expects two arguments to be passed).

```
a('Rod', 50);
b('Jane', 50);
c('Freddy', 50);
```

Now let's look at the error cases.

Functions:

```
// The parameters are not compatible.
var d: Example = function(special: boolean) { return 'Hello';}
```

Function calls:

```
// You haven't passed the args
a();
a('Rod');

// Args are wrong type
a(50, 'Rod');
a('Rod', true);

// Too many args
a('Rod', 50, true);
```

Answer (score 0):

Typescript does check function types - that's just a weird and special case where Typescript is letting you ignore function arguments in an assignment.

If you separate the variable declaration from the assignment, you'll then get type-errors during the assignment e.g.

```
var mySearch3 :(source: number, subString: string) => boolean;
var mySearch3 = function() { return true; }
```

Will produce this error in tsc 1.4.1:

```
error TS2403: Subsequent variable declarations must have the same type.  
Variable 'mySearch3' must be of type 
'(source: number, subString: string) => boolean', 
but here has type '() => boolean'.
```

Similarly, you'll get error's if you provide the arguments, but they have different types to the function definition. e.g.

```
var mySearch3 :(source: number, subString: string) => boolean =
    function(source:string, subString:string) { return true; }
```

Will give you this error:

```
error TS2322: Type '(source: string, subString: string) => boolean' is
not assignable to type '(source: number, subString: string) => boolean'.
Types of parameters 'source' and 'source' are incompatible.
Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'number'.
```

Comment: The error with `var mySearch3` is that you are redeclaring a variable with a different type to the original. Remove the `var` from the subsequent use of the variable and it will also allow the function without parameters.

Comment: yes, probably not super clearly expressed, but that was the point: that you can make the type-declaration be more strictly checked against the function definition by using this double declaration trick.

Answer (score 0):

Type validates here that function needs to be called with all required arguments. The implementation with less parameters match the need, just do not use all of them. If such check would be working then you could be doing function with three arguments and just cheat the type system:

```js
const mySearch3:  (source: Person, subString: string)=> boolean = (_source, _subString) => true
```

As you can see this function does not use any of them. What I want to prove is - such type check has no real sens, because you cannot validate if the argument is really in use inside the implementation. What is important for the caller is -> what type is the function returns and what arguments should be passed to it.