# Typescript function overloading and missing argument

Tags: javascript, typescript, overriding, overloading

I've declared a `wrapAsync` function with the following signature:

```
wrapAsync(fn: (req: Request, res: Response, next: NextFunction) => Promise<void>): RequestHandler
```

As you can see it expects to get a function with 3 arguments (req, res, next), non of them is optional.
When I register my routes, I'm doing the following:

```
app.get(myRouter, Utils.wrapAsync(myRouteHandler));
```

`myRouteHandler()` accepts only `req: Request, res: Response`, I would expect the `tsc` to fail on unmatched function, but it doesn't, how come?

Comment: This is covered in the FAQ: https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/FAQ#why-are-functions-with-fewer-parameters-assignable-to-functions-that-take-more-parameters

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28252843/typescript-dont-really-check-function-type

Comment: @TitianCernicova-Dragomir thank you. but it's usually better to inline the answer rather than referring to the documentation. Usually, when someones is asking a question, it's because they didn't find the answer by a search.

Comment: @klugjo , thanks. I've marked the question as a duplicate